# javascript prevent multicalls and disable the next ones

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following Script

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#reader').html5_qrcode(function (data) {
            $('#<%=txtCodigo.ClientID%>').val(data);
            $("LinkButton1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.UniqueID %>', '');

        },

            function (error) {
            }, function (videoError) {
                alert("No hay cámara");
            }
        );

    })
    ;

</script>
```

and this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="qrDetectado">    </asp:LinkButton>
```

So, when the reader gets a value , it's going to call a C# method qrDetectado, how ever, i have seen multiple times, that the method is called more than once, this is due to the script getting several values in a very short period of time, i'm just interested in the first one, so i want to avoid the script to run more than once i added

```
            $("LinkButton1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

in the script to disabled the linkbutton,and so far it's been working on my localserver, however i'm not sure if it will work in the live server, am i doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the better way is to set a boolean when the function is called

```
var uncalled = true; 
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#reader').html5_qrcode(function (data) {
    if(uncalled){
      uncalled = false;
      $('#<%=txtCodigo.ClientID%>').val(data);
      __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.UniqueID %>', '');
    }


  },
  function (videoError) {
    alert("No hay cámara");
  });

});
```

Comment: So by doing this, it's going to run  only once right?

Comment: correct the inner code will only run if the `uncalled` is true, and since you set it to false on the first call, it will only be true once